# What's good of using non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

It is known that in C++ we can have non-type template parameters like int:

```
template <class T, int size>
void f(){...}
```

I wonder how it is different from the ordinary way of passing a parameter into a function:

```
template <class T>
void f(int size) {...}
```

I think one difference is that for templates `size` is evaluated at compile-time and substituted as literals when instantiating the template. Thus I doubt (correct me if I'm wrong) that every different `size` value leads to the creation of new binary codes (the ".text"), which seems to be an overhead.

Can anyone tell when this is necessary and worthwhile?

Comment: It's pretty necessary for `std::array`.

Comment: Does either compile? How does the compiler determine `T`?

Comment: Besides `int` is a type

Comment: It's a quality-of-compiler issue as to how much code space the compiler uses.

Comment: A quick look at template meta programming might be helpful. http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/~gsd/halado_cpp/ch06s04.html. There are plenty of others on the web if you search for `template meta programming.

Comment: Could this potentially lead to code bloat if the template is used with lots of different values? Each instance would be duplicated code unless optimised out.

Comment: @Neo1989 There are plenty of use cases, your question is way to broad!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Thus I doubt (correct me if I'm wrong) that every different size value leads to the creation of new binary codes (the ".text"), which seems to be an overhead.

This is actually the case, and this is a common source of code bloat. You need to figure out when you want to generate different functions for each `N` and when you want a single function in which the compiler has less information (note that this is not just for performance, also for correctness).

Since Matt already brought a simple example, lets work on a function that takes an array by reference.:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t operateOnArray( T (&array)[N] )
{
     // Some complex logic, which could include:
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
       // complicated stuff
    }
}
```

The type of the argument is a reference to an array, the compiler will verify for you that the array truly has `N` elements (and it will deduce the type of the values in the array). This is a great improvement in type safety compared with some similar C style code:

```
size_t operateOnArray( T *array, size_t N)
{
     // Some complex logic, which could include:
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
       // complicated stuff
    }
}
```

In particular, the user can mistakenly pass the wrong value:

```
int array[10];
operateOnArray(arrah, 20); // typo!!!
```

Where in the first case the compiler will deduce the size and it will guarantee that it is correct.

You hit the nail in the head when you mentioned that this can potentially add to the code size, and that it can add quite a lot. Imagine that the function is complex enough that it does not get inlined, and imagine that in your program you end up calling the function with all sizes from 1 to 100. The program code *will* contain 100 instantiations of basically the same code where the only difference is the size.

There are solutions around this, like mixing the two approaches:

```
size_t operateOnArray( T *array, size_t N); // Possibly private, different name...
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t operateOnArray( T (&array)[N] ) {
   operateOnArray(array, N);
}
```

In this case, the compiler will have one single copy of the complex code, in the C-style function, and will generate 100 versions of the template, but those are simple, simple enough that the compiler *will* inline the code and transform the program into the equivalent of the C-style approach with guaranteed type safety.

> Can anyone tell when this is necessary and worthwhile?

It is **necessary** when the code inside the template requires the value as a compile time constant, for example in the code above, you cannot have a function argument that is a reference to an array of `N` elements where the `N` is only available at runtime. In other cases, like `std::array<T,N>` it is required to statically create an array of the proper size. No matter what, all examples shared that: the value needs to be known at compile time.

It is **worthwhile**, well, when it adds type safety to your program (see example above), or if it will allow stronger optimizations (a functor taking a function pointer/member function pointer as non-type argument can *inline* the function call).

And you should be aware that everything comes at a cost, in this case binary size. If the template is small enough that the code is likely to be inlined, don't worry, but if the code is quite complex, consider using hybrid approaches where you use a template argument where needed or if it provides a big advantage and regular arguments otherwise.

Comment: David thanks for the comprehensive answer. But I'm a bit confused with the sentence "the compiler will verify for you that the array truly has N elements". Within my C++ knowledge, when you pass an array to a function, the function doesn't care about its size. Say, `f(int &a[4])` is just the same as `f(int &a[])`. How does it work here?

Comment: @Neo1989 `f(int* a)` is equivalent to `f(int a[])` and `f(int a[42])`, but David uses reference to array which is different: `f(int (&a)[42])`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yep, I figure out this after some lookup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Passing size as a non-type template parameter is necessary when `f()` wants to allocate a C-style array of that size (e.g., as `f(){int array[size]; }`). If you pass size as a function parameter, your program won't compile because the size is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

As well as providing for much greater optimization ability, the parameters can be involved in template deduction (unlike function arguments), e.g. this is a common one for finding how many items are in a named array:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t lengthof( T (&array)[N] )
{
     return N;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t foo[] = L"The quick brown fox";
    std::wcout << "\"" << foo << "\" has " << lengthof(foo) - 1 << " characters.\n";
}
```

Probably the compiler will calculate the length at compiletime and substitute that directly into the `wcout << .......` line, not even making a runtime function call.

Answer (score 0):

[Compile-time dimensional analysis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/dimensional-analysis.html). This one has helped me detect errors early when implementing physics simulations.